# .NET - Set all Entity current values to new values without specifying separate properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have two entities, one is the one in the database the other is the new value i received from the controller.

Now i want to update the entity in the Database without specifying all the different properties;

Instead of:

```
public async Task UpdateFoo(Foo fooNew){
    Foo fooDb = await context.Foo
        .Include(f => f.Child)
        .Where(f => f.Id == 1)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    fooDb.Value01 = fooNew.Value01;
    fooDb.Value02 = fooNew.Value02;
    fooDb.Child.ValueA = fooNew.Child.ValueA;

    context.SaveChangesAsync()
}
```

I want to do something like;

```
public async Task UpdateFoo(Foo fooNew){
    Foo fooDb = await context.Foo
        .Include(f => f.Child)
        .Where(f => f.Id == 1)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    fooDb = fooNew;

    context.SaveChangesAsync()
}
```

I tried using CurrentValues.SetValues;

```
context.Entry(fooDb).CurrentValues.SetValues(fooNew);
```

This results in an error because of the key being marked as modified;

> The property 'Id' on entity type 'Foo' is part of a key and so cannot
>   be modified or marked as modified.

Is there a way to overwrite and save all entity properties (and entity child properties) without specifying them one by one?

Comment: `CurrentValues.SetValues` is indeed the intended way for updating the primitive properties. It doesn't throw exception in latest official EF Core 2.0.1 So you either are using old EFC version with bug, or `fooNew.Id` is not the one used for `fooDb` (== 1?).

Comment: Why dont use reflection?

Comment: For as long as the model has an `Id` value, you don't need to pre-fetch it from the db in-order to update it's values. 

Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

How about you start by attaching the model to a `DbSet<T>` then telling EF tracker to update all its fields whenever you call `.SaveChanges()`

Sample code looks like this.

```
public async Task UpdateFoo(Foo foo_updated)
{
    foo_updated = context.Set<Foo>()
                         .Attach(foo_updated);

    context.Entry(foo_updated).State = EntityState.Modified;
    context.Entry(foo_updated.Child).State = EntityState.Modified;

    context.SaveChangesAsync()
}
```